# Is there any function can take value infinity?

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading the book *real analysis* by Stein. At the bottom of page 27, it shows

> We begin by considering only real-valued functions $f$ on $R^d$
> , which we
> allow to take on the infinite values +∞ and −∞, so that $f(x)$ belongs
> to the extended real numbers$$−∞\leq f(x)\leq+∞$$

From my understanding, $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ with domain $(0,+∞)$ and range $(0,+∞)$ is not taking any infinity value in its domain, although it has a unbounded range.

Is $f(x) = +∞$ for all $x\in R$, an example of function taking infinity value?

Comment: Yes, why not? $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty \}$.

Comment: Another example is $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ defined by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}\infty & \text{if $x=0$}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x)=+\infty$ is a perfectly fine example. For $\frac{1}{x}$, you can also include $\infty$ in its codomain as follows. Define
$$f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$$ by $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ if $x\neq 0$, and $f(x)=\infty$ if $x=0$.